# fill color on imageview

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, viewcontroller

I have taken a view and inserted scrollview on it using nib.  Then I've added an image using imageview dynamically..Now what should I do to fill color on that image.

Answer (score 0):

What your after isn't exactly clear,

If you want to make the entire image a single colour, remove the image and set the `.backgroundColor`.

If you have a image that has some transparency you make a transparent colours a single colour by the same method above.

background colours can also be set in nibs; (Select imageView, goto Inspector window, first tab)

If you want to colour shapes within the image that an entirely different thing.

Comment: hey thank u for giving the answer.   And yeah!! I want to colour shapes within the image. now what to do??

Comment: This is not a trivial question and you have not been very descriptive about your problem. Do you know where the 'shapes' are before hand? are you simply doing colour replacement? shape recognition? will they always be the same colour? Lastly,I recommend you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq